# Using String Size to Declare Array Size?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, size

Sorry beginner here. I'm trying to get the string size from the cin function, then use that to declare array size.  But it's saying:

> line 17: request for member 'size' in 'x', which is non-class type 'std::string long int'.

It works fine without the array though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y;
    string x[y];
    cout << "Enter sequence" << endl;
    cin >> x[y];
    y = x.size;

    for (int i = 0; i > y; i++)
        cout x[i];

    cout << "The size of the sequence is " << x.size() << " characters." << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't declare arrays with a runtime size. Use `std::vector` for that. You might also be confusing the condition of a for loop.

Comment: I haven't learned about vectors yet, is there another way?

Comment: I think what you're going for is just `std::string x; std::cin >> x; std::cout << x;`. It plays nicely with input and output. It looks like you're trying to use a combination of `std::string` and `char[]`. Aside, vectors are much simpler than the other way, though.

Comment: @Foxic: No. Learn about vectors *now* and you'll be a better person for it. It's worth the 30 minutes of your time.

Comment: @chris dude! Stop writing answers as comments. When you do, I feel bad adding my own answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I'm not overly sure what the OP is trying to accomplish because the syntax looks foreign to me in the way it's being used. I agree with your sentiment, though, and yes, have been told way too many times.

Comment: I believe there is a formatting error in the error message which you say you get. Please edit your question to include the correct error message. (Hint: put the error message on its own line indented four space so that all the `<`s and `>`s appear correctly.)

Comment: I usually put errors in block quotes, as I have done to this one, but there's another thing: I think you might have some extra text on the end. The only error I've seen like that ends at the `std::string` part.

Comment: Also, I'd like to back up and ask what you are trying to do. The title of your question doesn't exactly match the code. What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, of all declaring an array as you do is not allowed. Let's take a look at these two lines of code

```
int y;
string x[y];
```

In the second line of code, what is the value of `y`? It could be anything. Certainly the compiler doesn't know, and the array size *must* be determined at compile-time.

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Use pointers and dynamically allocate an array.
2. Use std::vector and let the standard library take care of the dynamic allocation.

IMO, both are tools which you should have in your programmer tool belt, so you should learn how to do both. You should also learn the advantages and disadvantages of either approach so that you can choose the correct one to solve a problem.

Finally, the error message that you get means that an array does not have a member called `size()`. If you fix this using solution 1. above, you will need to keep track of the size yourself.

Comment: Ha, I was so knackered when I answered that question.. actually went to bed immediately after :) Surprised there wasn't a great amount of downvotes. +1 For *correct* answer :P